# Suitable aggregations (mean, median or something else) to make features?

Tags: classification, feature-engineering, feature-construction

Trying to solve a classification problem using a large number of features, some are individual numbers from a signal while others are aggregates of values to create a feature (median, mean etc).

I take multiple aggregations(m values) of the same signals (n values) to create a relatively large set of ~100 features (m*n values).

Is it okay to have multiple aggregations of the same data as features? If not, which one should I pick, and how?

The data has numerical and categorical features and I use one-hot-encoding for the categorical ones before feeding them to scikit-learn's RandomForestClassifier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of model you use whether highly correlated features are problematic or not. In general they of course add less information than  low correlated features but as long as you have enough rows (10:1 rows vs columns as a very loose guideline) and a slightly more complex model to train, it generally helps your cause in my experience. As always you can test performance using a validation set.